# PHP Add variables to json array

Tags: php, sql, arrays, json

I have a problem. I execute `SELECT` from my database to get user data. Now I also got a few variables beside the `$result` from the query. I want all of the data added to my json. Here is my current code:

```
if($result->num_rows == 1) 
{           
    $access_token = "myToken";
    $expires_in = 3600;

    while($row = $result->fetch_object())
    {               
        $arrTotal[] = array($row);
    }

    $myObj->access_token = $access_token;
    $myObj->expires_in = $expires_in;

    $data = array();
    $data['user'] = $arrTotal;
    $data['token'] = $myObj;
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

This current code results in the following json:

```
{
   "user":[
      [
         {
            "Id":"0",
            "Username":"Vreesie",
            "ProfilePicture":""
         }
      ]
   ],
   "token":{
      "access_token":"myToken",
      "expires_in":"3600"
   }
}
```

But I want it to look like this:

```
{
   "user":[
      [
         {
            "Id":"0",
            "Username":"Vreesie",
            "ProfilePicture":""
         }
      ]
   ],
   "token":[
      [
         {
            "access_token":"myToken",
            "expires_in":"3600"
         }
      ]
   ]
}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply with `$data['token'] = [[$myObj]];`

Comment: Review: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. I would recommend you to check SO's [official How to Answer article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) along with the comprehensive [blog post](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully/) from [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet).
I mark your answer for deletion.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, tokens inside an array.
Create a nested array for token.

```
$myObj[] = [
    'access_token' => $access_token,
    'expires_in' => $expires_in
]
```

Or you can also use `$data['token']` as array and push your `$myObj` array inside.

```
$data['token'][] = $myObj;
```

Comment: Good, but I think it's $data['token'][] = $myObj; more meaningful